# PayPal Adaptive Payments / Is the possible use-case possible?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm currently researching implementing PayPal Adaptive Payments in our service.

I'm interested if the following use-case can work?

---

1) Customer purchases a service through our website. Customer pays us ("the service") 10% of the fee through Standard Payments (customer => service).

2) During this moment, we would like to get the customers approval to bill them for the remainder (90%) at a future date, but this time to a 3rd party receiver ("subcontractor").

3) After said period, we (the service) would like to initiate the delayed/preapproved payment from the customer to said "subcontractor".

---

** It is important that the 2nd payment (from the customer to the subcontractor) not involve us officially (meaning: they should see where exactly the money came from)

Would love if someone could tell if this is doable and possibly push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If the total amount is under $2000 USD, this can conceivably be done with Adaptive Payments Preapprovals.

However, preapprovals are so powerful that it is difficult to obtain sufficient permission to use this functionality on a live PayPal account.

A lesser solution would be to use Delayed Chained Payments  (action=PAY_PRIMARY in the initial PAY API call).  However, this would officially involve you -- i.e., the subcontractor would see the money as coming into their PayPal account from yours, and you would need to pass the originating buyer's information to them separately.